# App Crashes After Verifying OTP Using Firebase Phone Auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

Edit: It has been solved.

This question is not similar to previous ones. I have referred to
[app crash while using firebase phone Auth in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65839861/app-crash-while-using-firebase-phone-auth-in-android) but my app is still crashing.

So I am trying to design a chat app where the user can login with OTP provided by Firebase but when I enter the OTP(right/wrong) received on phone the app crashes. If someone can please guide me it'll be fantastic.

**Note: I have included the implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0" dependency but the app is still crashing when I try to verify the OTP**

The *main error* I am getting is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.commutify, PID: 5168
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.commutify.otpAuthentication$2.onClick(otpAuthentication.java:61)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6647)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6620)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:791)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26346)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7081)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
```

So here is my code for class where **OTP Authentication** takes place

```
    TextView mchangenumber;
    EditText mgetotp;
    android.widget.Button mverifyotp;
    String enteredotp;

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    ProgressBar mprogressbarofotpauth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_authentication);

        mchangenumber = findViewById(R.id.changenumber);
        mverifyotp = findViewById(R.id.verifyotp);
        mgetotp = findViewById(R.id.getotp);
        mprogressbarofotpauth = findViewById(R.id.progressbarofmain);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mchangenumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(otpAuthentication.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mverifyotp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enteredotp = mgetotp.getText().toString();
                if(enteredotp.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Your OTP First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    mprogressbarofotpauth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String coderecieved = getIntent().getStringExtra("otp");
                    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(coderecieved, enteredotp);
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    mprogressbarofotpauth.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(otpAuthentication.this, setProfile.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        mprogressbarofotpauth.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Here are my **gradle dependencies**

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.5.1'
}
```

If someone wants the **MainActivity where I enter the number for verification** here it is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mgetphonenumber;
    android.widget.Button msendotp;
    CountryCodePicker mcountrycodepicker;
    //extra m is added for for easily assigning XML ID to Java ID
    String countrycode;
    String phonenumber;

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    ProgressBar mprogressbarofmain;


    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    String codesent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mcountrycodepicker = findViewById(R.id.countrycodepicker);
        msendotp = findViewById(R.id.sendotpbutton);
        mgetphonenumber = findViewById(R.id.getphonenumber);
        mprogressbarofmain = findViewById(R.id.progressbarofmain);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        countrycode = mcountrycodepicker.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus();

        //below segment is for those who want to change their countries
        mcountrycodepicker.setOnCountryChangeListener(new CountryCodePicker.OnCountryChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCountrySelected() {
                countrycode = mcountrycodepicker.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus();
            }
        });

        //for sending otp
        msendotp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String number;
                number = mgetphonenumber.getText().toString();
                //if the user doesn't enters the number
                if(number.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Your Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                //since a number has 10 digits
                else if(number.length()<10){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter a Valid Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    mprogressbarofmain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //concatenates country code and the number added by the user
                    phonenumber = countrycode + number;

                    PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(firebaseAuth)
                            .setPhoneNumber(phonenumber)
                            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .setActivity(MainActivity.this)
                            .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)
                            .build();

                    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

                }
            }
        });

        //function to verify the number for otp

        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                //how to automatically fetch OTP(for future)
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull  FirebaseException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull  String s, @NonNull  PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                //if the function runs successfully, the code is sent
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OTP is Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mprogressbarofmain.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                codesent = s;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, otpAuthentication.class);
                intent.putExtra("otp", codesent);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

    }
    //for checking if the user exists(in order to open the chat screen)
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!=null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, chatscreen.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should Delete this question.

Comment: I am getting "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem not related to Firebase.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Are you sure your progress bar is initialized? Maybe findViewById doesn't do what it needs to do? Maybe on layout, progressbar view id not same?